# Candidate search sort order in careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I was wondering how candidates are sorted when searched by employers in careers site.

An employer will perform a search by inserting a list of skills and a location (plus other minor parameters). When my profile will be included in the result? If I've a work experience in the tag or if I've upvotes about that tag?

How are the result being ordered? My profile had 74 search hits and 0 views and I think, this is because it's probably ranking quite low. For this reason I would like to understand more about the sort order. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific are subject to change as we look at the data of how employers use it, but right now:

**Location** and other criteria (objectives, student, etc) are used as a filter, not a sort.  Either you match the criteria and are shown, or you don't.

**Skills** are used to sort candidates.  For every tag used on your profile or in your SO profile, we calculate a score for you.  When an employer searches 3 tags, we sum your score in each tag and sort by that total score.

The exact score is a secret to keep people from gaming it, but it looks at everything on your CV, and the more information you give us the better your chances.  So if you don't have any linked SO accounts or open source projects, or are missing some experience or education entries, they are a good place to start.